# Mesh wont move with the rig

Tags: rigging, armature

I Ripped a model from a game, Risk of Rain 2, and rigged it, perfectly following the instructions of [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DS885Sk1gSs)

Yet it will not move in pose mode with the rig.

Rigged model: https://we.tl/t-NDKCRZb4hT

Unrigged model: https://we.tl/t-ufGZRST5ou

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have duplicate vertices in your mesh.  When you attempted to parent the mesh to the rig, an error flashed on the bottom of the screen and you must not have noticed it:

[image: Bone Heat Weighting]

99 times out of 100 this means ***You have duplicate vertices in your mesh.***  Blender's algorithm for automatically assigning weights will fail if the mesh isn't *[manifold](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/glossary/index.html#term-Manifold)*, and this is the most common reason why a mesh won't be manifold. (See below for a definition of manifold.)

To fix this, using your first blend file as an example

1. Remove the existing attempt to parent

   - Switch from *Pose* to *Object* mode. (Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>–<kbd>Tab</kbd>)
   - Select the object `CommandoMesh`
   - Go to *Object properties* in the properties editor.
   - In the *Relations Tab* remove `Rig` from the *Parent* field by clicking on the x.
   - Go to *Modifiers* in the properties editor.
   - Delete the *Armature* modifier.
   - Go to *Object Data properties* in the properties editor.
   - In the *Vertex Groups* panel, click the down arrow to bring up a menu.
   - Select delete all groups.
2. Fix the duplicate vertices.

   - Switch to *Edit* mode. (Shortcut: <kbd>Tab</kbd>)
   - Make sure all vertices are selected by typing <kbd>A</kbd>
   - Bring up the merge menu. (Shortcut: <kbd>m</kbd>)
   - Select *By Distance*.

You should see another message appear on the bottom.  *Please pay attention to messages that appear there.*  It will tell you that you had 2442 duplicate vertices but they were removed.

[image: Duplicates removed message]

3. Now the parenting will work

   - Switch to *Object* mode. (Shortcut: <kbd>Tab</kbd>)
   - Shift-select `Rig` to add it to the selections.
   - *Parent* `CommandoMesh` to `Rig`. (Shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>–<kbd>P</kbd> and select *With Automatic Weights*.

There will now be no error message and the rig will move the mesh.

The Blender manual describes [Manifold](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/glossary/index.html#term-Manifold) thusly:

> Manifold meshes, also called ‘water-tight’ meshes, define a closed non-self-intersecting volume

## Tip: The Info Window

Often we miss the information messages that appear on the bottom of the Blender window.  When an operation fails, it's possible to open the *Info* editor window.  You can find it in the *Scripting Workspace* or you can open it in any of your current panels using the drop down menu:

[image: Drop down menu for selecting editors, with info editor highlighted]

Scroll backward through it looking for the various info or error icons.  Often they'll help you solve the problem, or at least make it easier to search for a solution online.

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU